# select item from HTML page using python selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

wish you have a nice day.
I am trying to finish one of my blocks and, I am stuck in it.
I have tried the below codes though there was no success. only the first two drivers work and, my goal is selecting that "Daily report Dec 2019" option in the psiToolPan div. Many thanks in advance.

[image]

here is my block:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("smr")
for e in elements:
    e.click()
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("smr-more")
for e in elements:
    e.click()    

select_obj = 
select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='smr']//div[@class='smr- 
more']//strong[@id='psiTool']"))
select_obj.select_by_visible_text('All')

# courses_button = driver.find_element_by_name('psiTool').click()    
# courses_button = driver.find_element_by_id('psiToolPan').click()
# courses_button = driver.find_element_by_id('templateList').click()

driver.find_element_by_link_text('Selecting a template').click();
# searchElem.send_keys('Daily report Dec 2019')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element You are trying to interact it is inside iframe id `dashboard_iframe`.
you need to switch to iframe first in order to access the element.

Induce `WebDriverWait` And `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`()
And 
Induce `WebDriverWait` And `element_to_be_clickable`()

```
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"dashboard_iframe")))
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.smr"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.smr-more"))).click()
element=WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#templateList")))
select=Select(element)
select.select_by_visible_text("Daily report Dec 2019")
```

Import following libraries to execute above code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**EDIT**:

Induce JavaScript Executor to click.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"dashboard_iframe")))
elementclick=WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.smr")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elementclick)
elementclick=WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.smr-more")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elementclick)
element=WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#templateList")))
select=Select(element)
select.select_by_visible_text("Daily report Dec 2019")
```

Comment: Thanks for sparing your time on my problem, I have tried your solution and, I got an exception that </div> is not clickable here is the excact message:

Comment: element click intercepted: Element <div class="smr">...</div> is not clickable at point (517, 0). Other element would receive the click: <div id="rightMain" class="smr-right">...</div>

Comment: @MahyarAzad : Check the Edited answer which should click the element.Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, previous errors have fixed and, now, I get below error: (#templateList list doesn't work)

Comment: raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: element=WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#templateList")))

Comment: should we select <strong id="psiTool"> ?

Comment: @MahyarAzad: can you share your url?

Answer (score 0):

According to quality of your question, answer is:

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

(note: you should user css-selector or xpath - `"//option[@title='Daily report Dec 2019'][@value='8956']"`)

Comment: select_obj = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@title='Daily report Dec 2019'][@value='8956']").select()

Comment: @MahyarAzad can you give the url? I'll try it.

Comment: I hate to say this, I cannot give the UID since it's lead to confidential HUAWEI data :(

Comment: I'm glad for you :) If my answer helped you, mark it as ANSWER, plz :)

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"dashboard_iframe")))
elementclick=WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.smr")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elementclick)
elementclick=WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.smr-more")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elementclick)
courses_button = driver.find_element_by_id('psiTool').click()
courses_button = driver.find_element_by_id('psiToolPan').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@title='Daily report Dec 2019'][@value='8956']").click()
```

Comment: @Kunduk Thank you so much. the above codes worked prefectly.

Comment: Oh! please accept my apologies, I am a newbie. I post those codes to show you it is working/